# Recursion cin.getline() doesn't want to ask for input

Tags: c++, parsing, recursion

Here is the code:

```
void Reader::read(short& in) {
    char* str = new char[6];
    char* strbeg = str;
    cin.getline(str, 6);

    in = 0;
    int value = 0;
    short sign = 1;

    if (*str == '+' || *str == '-') {
        if (*str == '-' ) sign = -1;
        str++;
    }

    while (isdigit(*str)) {
        value *= 10;
        value += (int) (*str - '0');
        str++;
        if (value > 32767) {
            cout.write("Error, value can't fit short. Try again.\n", 41);
            delete[] strbeg;
            read(in);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (sign == -1) { value *= -1; }

    in = (short) value;

    delete[] strbeg;

    return;
}
```

What happens is that if I type 999999999, it calls itself but on fourth line it's not gonna ask for input again. Debugger couldn't give much info as it is more language-specific question. Thank you in advance. Have a nice day!
Yes, the goal is to parse input as short. I know about losing 1 from min negative, wip :)

=== edit ===

I've tried goto... No, same thing. So it's not about visible variables or addresses, I guess.

=== edit ===

I can't use operator >> as it is forbidden by the task.

Comment: Not the problem, but there's no point in doing dynamic allocation here.

Comment: @molbdnilo getline requires pointer. the whole task is to avoid using overload (cin >> a).

Comment: try `char str[6]`.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake 1) Why are you using [`std::basic_istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), instead of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? 2) If you even looked at the documentation of `std::basic_istream::getline` (linked above), you would see that `failbit` is set, when `count-1` characters are extracted.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius so the answer is to use getline, not cin.getline, right?

Comment: @felix I can't. operator >> is forbidden.

Comment: @molbdnilo string size, isn't it?

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake I thought about "the other" getline. Sorry.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake 1) Why can't you use `char str[6]`, instead of dynamic allocation, exactly? who was even talking about `operator>>` here? 2) The true answer is - do **any** research before asking on SO. And, reading documentation,  should, _always_ be the first thing, when some function is misbehaving. You can, technically, use either, I was just asking why did you prefer the one, that you used.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I've got your point. Thanks. But not an answer anyway.

Comment: I'll try static array lil later. But I still wonder why it's not working like this. I'd like to know for the future.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake And that's why I didn't post an answer. You can either 1) have a read through documentation, and figure out how to fix your code in 5 minutes, or 2) wait for undefined amount of time, for someone kind enough to spell the issues out for you. EDIT: Why do you feel the need for static array? No one even suggested that.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No real point of being unkind. Also answers like "go read doc" or "go google it" are not welcomed by SO as far as I know. It is not that common problem to be mad. Thank you again for your respond.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake Is it possible to use std::string? It can make things much simpler. otherwise, you will have to deal with those inputs left in the stream.

Comment: @felix I've tried cin.ignore, not gonna work. string as a data type is forbidden, too.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake 1) If `std::string` is forbidden - you are **not** being taught C++. 2) As I already mentioned - that's why I didn't put that as an answer. Even though I can see a double-standard from you. You are telling me what sort of answers are not welcome on SO, but, are questions, that don't show **any** research effort, welcome on SO? As I already mentioned - documentation should've been the first place you looked.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius no, I see different problem. and that's y people leave SO. this is so not like open-source community. I know you probably don't want to be here for solving my tasks, but it is a part of learning process. if you say 'no string no cpp' you are very mistaken as I think. the point of learning cpp was to understand how it all works inside, no need of high-level stuff like string type. I am learning Java+Android separately and I see a difference. Thank you again, Sir, but you hurt more than help.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake1) So.. You are saying, that people are leaving SO, because SO has rules? Great leap of logic. If it were up to me - reading entire [help] should be mandatory before asking 2) `std::string` is a fundamental language feature. Why wouldn't you want to use it? If you want to _understand how it all works inside_ C, or even assembly, is better choices for that. C++ is also a high level language, but, with an emphasis on performance, unlike Java (whose emphasis is on portability). It _is_ possible to write C-like code in C++, but that is, more often than not, a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

999999999 will cause an overflow, thus failbit is set for cin. Then your program reach read(in), then the `cin.getline()`. Here, beacause of failbit, cin will not ask any input again.

If you tried to figure out why in my code cin do ask for more input, you might find out all this by yourself.

---

I write you an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char str[6];

  short x = 0;
  bool flag = false;
  while (flag == false) {
    cin.getline(str, 6);
    flag = cin.good();
    if (flag) { // if read successfully
      char *p = str;
      if (*p=='-') // special case for the first character
        ++p;

      while (*p && *p>='0' && *p<='9')
        ++p;
      if (*p) // there is a non digit non '\0' character
        flag = false;
    }

    if (flag == false) {
      cout << "An error occurred, try try again." << endl;
      if (!cin.eof()) {
        cin.unget(); // put back the possibly read '\n'
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
      }
      cin.clear();
    } else {
      // str is now ready for parsing
      // TODO: do your parsing work here

      // for exemple x = atoi(str); 
    }
  }

  std::cout << x << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

As we have discussed, you don't need new.

Check whether the string read is clean before parsing. If you mix checking and parsing, things will be complicated.

And you don't need recursion.

Read characters from stream by `istream::getline` seems to be the only option we have here. And when an error occurred, this function really doesn't tell us much, we have to deal with overflow and other problem separately.

Comment: I haven't asked you to rewrite my code. I asked to tell me why it behaves as it behaves. I can rewrite it to work without asking on SO. Your code is also no better, at the very least it does not behave like atoi() itself. how I will parse double type with your atoi() at the end huh? I mean I can parse integer part of float with atoi, but not floating part probably. And nothing for double.

Comment: I didn't rewrite your code. I tried to give an example on how to read input, nothing more. I am sorry if I failed in helping you with it. Parsing isn't the topic here, if you have problems in parsing, you can post another question.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake BTW, I didn't say that I can write better code or imply this. I was giving a working example, not engaging in a competition. I did say that your code really has lots of problem, if you feel offended, I apologise.

Comment: Thank you for your help! And sorry for misunderstanding.